# Display a single element of an array according to its ID REACT

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, post

I would like to make an articles system on my site created with React, but I'm a bit lost.

I have a JS array that allows me to make a loop to display my articles. When I click on an article, it sends me to the right page thanks to the `<Link />`. But here is my problem, how to display the content of the article I clicked on? I tried to get the slug of the article and to compare it to the ID of the elements of my array but I have to admit that I don't know where I stand.

Here is my code, it only returns a `<h1>Title: { id }</h1>` (which is the correct slug every time)

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";
import '../styles/Single.css'

const posts = [
    {
        source:
          "./images/esdexp-th-homepage.jpg",
        content: {
          name: "Expérience ESD",
          link:"/post/ESDexp",
          idSlug :"ESDexp"
        }
      },
    {
      source:
        "./images/vacui-th-homepage.jpg",
      content: {
        name: "Horror Vacui",
        link:"/post/horrorvacui",
        idSlug : "horrorvacui"
      }
    },
    {
      source:
      "./images/meteo-th-homepage.jpg",
      name: "Forecast",
      link:"/post/forecast",
      idSlug :"forecast"
    },
    {
      source:
      "./images/ami-th-homepage.jpg",
      name: "Citroën Ami",
        link:"/post/ami",
        idSlug :"ami"
    },
    {
        source:
        "./images/musee-th-homepage.jpg",
        content: {
          name: "Musée Home",
          link:"/post/musee",
          idSlug :"musee"
        }
      },
  ];

export default function ParamsExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/post/:id" children={<Child />} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Child() {
  let { id } = useParams();
  console.log({id})
  var itemPost =  posts.filter(function(displayPost) {
    return displayPost.idSlug == { id };
    });
    console.log(itemPost)
  return (
    <div>
        <div className="single-container rev-block">
      <div className="single-content-container">
      <h1>Title : {id}</h1>
      </div>
  </div>
    </div>
    
  );
}
```

I hope I've made this as clear as possible,
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working because the posts data is not consistent. The idSlug of some posts are inside the content object.

To handle that situation you have to check if the idSlug is not undefined, and if it is, set the post slug or ID to use the idSlug inside the content object.

A working example can be found here.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-cannon-7kxiz?file=/src/App.js

The useParams has been replaced with an actual ID or slug of a post because the sandbox does not allow routing.

This line handles the inconsistency of the posts data.

```
 let post_slug = displayPost.idSlug
      ? displayPost.idSlug
      : displayPost.content.idSlug;
```

Also, please note that filter returns another array, so you have to access post or the itemPost using the first index.

```
<h1>Title : {itemPost[0].content.name}</h1>
```

And of course, you can also use the id returned by the useParams.

Comment: Thank you it works ! But onnly when i an ID and not useParams. When i try with useParams, i have `TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

```
try this.

    function Child() {
       let { id } = useParams();
       console.log({id})
       var itemPost =  posts.filter(function(displayPost) {
            return displayPost.idSlug === id ; // you don't need those curly braces.
        });
    console.log(itemPost)
    return (
    <div>
        <div className="single-container rev-block">
         <div className="single-content-container">
          <h1>Title : {id}</h1>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,

However, I have a Javascript error, , 
```
./src/pages/Single.js
SyntaxError: D:\...\site\src\pages\Single.js: Unterminated JSX contents (77:9)

  75 |    <div className="single-content-container">
  76 |    <h1>Title : {id}</h1>
> 77 |    </div>
     |          ^
  78 |  ); }
  79 |
  80 |
```

Comment: Please check the number of opening tags should be equal to the closing tag. I think closing tags for the div tag is missing.

Comment: Thanks a lot I think it works, so if I want to display the title of my post, I have to do for example a <h4>{displayPost.name}</h4>?

Comment: Yes @leoop0 . To access a property of an object either you can use dot notation ( obj.property) or square bracket notation (obj["property"]). And if the answer helped you don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Get the help of `<Link />` to pass the state from parent component to child component. Make the parent component like this:

```
<Link to={{
      pathname:{'/post/post.id'},
      state:{
         post:post
      }
}}>
```

Then you can get the post in the child component as below:

```
function child(props){
    const post = props.location.state.post
}
```

Also, try to make the routing as below. It won't make much complications:

```
<Route path="/post/:id" component={Child} />
```